# Laravel-Update another table with sum from one table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to get cumulative salary monthly(the table name is cumulative_salary) from another table(the table name is salary), then update the data. I just can 'get()' the data but i can't update. I'm so confusing and i don't know the correct syntax. So, this is my code.

```
 $data = DB::table('salary')
    ->where('employee_id', $employee_id)
    ->leftJoin('employees', 'salary.employee_id', '=', 'employees.id')
    ->select(DB::raw('SUM(salary_overtime) as `salary`'),
    DB::raw('YEAR(overtime_date) year, MONTH(overtime_date) month'))
    ->groupby('month','year')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I would suggest doing this in MySQL, but your question suggests that you want Laravel.

Comment: @GordonLinoff maybe your suggest can help me